# How to retrieve the data from function inside class to list in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to display data using `ListView.builder`, but I keep getting null error. I think that's because my code is not structured right. How can I fix it?

*Class:*

```dart
class Parent {
  late String? pContent;
  List childClass = [Child];
  Parent(this.pContent);
}

class Child {
  late int? id;
  late String? cContent;
  Child(this.id, this.cContent);
}
```

*List in Model:*

```dart
class Data {
  MyList() {
    List<Parent> pc = [];

    pc.add(Parent('abc'));
    pc[0]
        .childClass
        .add(Child(id: 1, cContent: 'This is child class content 1'));

    pc.add(Parent('xyz'));
    pc[1]
        .childClass
        .add(Child(id: 2, cContent: 'This is child class content 2'));
  }
}
```

*ListView:*

```dart
class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  var data = Data();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.pc.childClass.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(
              data.pc.childClass.cContent,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution please try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Application',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var data = Data();

  @override
  initState() {
    data.MyList();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.prnt.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Container(
                  child: Text(
                data.prnt[i].childClass[0].cContent.toString(),
              ));
            }));
  }
}

class Parent {
  String pContent;
  List<Child> childClass = [];

  Parent(this.pContent);
}

class Child {
  int id;
  String cContent;

  Child(this.id, this.cContent);
}

class Data {
  List<Parent> prnt = [];

  void MyList() {
    Child ch1 = Child(1, "this is child class content 1");
    prnt.add(Parent('abc'));
    prnt[0].childClass.add(ch1);
    Child ch2 = Child(2, "this is child class content 2");
    prnt.add(Parent('xyz'));
    prnt[1].childClass.add(ch2);
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Make `pc` global.

```dart
class Data{
    List<Parent> pc = []; // its becomes accessible.
    MyList(){
        pc.add(Parent('abc'));
        pc[0].childClass.add(Child(id: 1,cContent: 'This is child class content 1'));

        pc.add(Parent('xyz'));
        pc[1].childClass.add(Child(id: 2,cContent: 'This is child class content 2'));
    }
}
```

- Don't forget to call `myList` function before accessing `data`.

```dart
... build(...){
  data.MyList(); // bad. Next point is preferred way
  ...
  return ...
```

OR

```dart
... initState(...) {
  data.MyList();
  ...
```

- You might prefer creating a named constructor for sample values. This way, you need not call another function again.

```dart
class Data {
  Data.samples1() {
    // content inside myList
  }
```

---

Other Tips:

- You don't need `late` keyword with nullable(eg: String?) datatypes.
- `List childClass = [Child];` is not an empty list. Try changing to `List<Child> childClass = [];`
- It's a good practice to mention return type.

```dart
class Data {
    void myList() {
```

- Dart follows `camelCase` naming convention.

Comment: Hi thank you soo much for your reply. i corrected all the steps you've mentioned above. now i'm getting error "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0"

Comment: did you call myList function?

Comment: sorry sir, nope. where do i need to call that.?

Comment: hope new answer helps